# How do I convert this to EJS?

Tags: node.js, swig, ejs

I'm following a tutorial where the author is using Swig Template Engine (http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/) and he has this bit of code

```
<div id="captchaHolder">
    {% autoescape false %} {{captcha}} {% endautoescape %}
</div>
```

I'm not quite sure what he's doing here but I know it's some sort of logic tag. I'm trying to convert it to the equivalent in EJS. I've tried numerous things and they'll all wrong. If anyone knows the syntax for both these languages that would be very helpful. At the moment I'm stopped dead in my tracks because I don't understand what's happening here. The tutorial can be found here. http://www.codeoftheory.com/blog/post/how-to-create-a-contact-form-with-a-captcha-in-nodejs

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the answer was partially right in front of my face. I googled auto escaping text in EJS.

```
<div id="captchaHolder">
    <%- captcha  %>
</div>
```